# What are the possibly situations that .net Viewstate could stop working?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, viewstate

Consider the following code:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        If Page.IsPostBack Then
            If ViewState("test") IsNot Nothing Then
                Response.Write((ViewState("test").ToString))
            Else 
                Response.Write("Viewstate is empty.")
            End If
        Else
            ViewState("test") = "viewstate is working."
        End If
    End Sub
```

This code doesn't work on a particular page in my application. Viewstate is not turned off in the Page directive. I can't figure out what's going on. : \

Oh i just figured it out. See if you notice it.

> .<

Comment: I assume by not working you mean hitting: Response.Write("Viewstate is empty.")?

Comment: Is the ViewState hidden field written to the client on the first GET?

Comment: going to delete this embarassment of a question

Comment: Please reply to your own post, instead of editing you post, and mark you reply as answer. :) I just replied, and did not figure out that you have answered it your self :)

Comment: No don't it's a good reference for others!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, someone had changed the Page_Load event to handle Page.Init

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off viewstate from the config file too.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <Pages EnableViewState="false" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: i voted up but its not the issues a viewsstate tag is actually getting rendered on the page. i feel like im going insane here.

Answer (score 1):

Are you SURE that you make a postback?

Do it write "Viewstate is empty"? Or just nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't answer your own post...

I'd say you are checking IsPostBack and accessing ViewState at the wrong stages:

```
Handles Me.Init
```

That should be

```
Handles Me.Load
```

right?

---

For debugging such headaches in ASP.NET I'd also like to add that tracing can often helps a lot.

You can enable tracing by adding this to web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This will append the stack trace and whatnot to the end of every page, so you can trace the execution and (hopefully) find out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was writing data to a ViewState on Page_Init. This data was displaying nice on Page_Load and Page_PreRender, but it was not being persisted to page at the end of life-cycle. After postback ViewState was empty.

**So, make sure that you write to ViewState AFTER Page_Init.**